# jQuery code inside already existing .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering how I can put the jQuery inside my script in the HTML file into my already existing `.js` file. I have already linked to `"WebSocket.js"` in my HTML, and I want to put the jQuery code inside of that file.

The `"WebSocket.js"` file is already existing javascript code.

Here is my html:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="WebSocket.js" ></script>
</head>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.lightbox').click(function(){
                $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
            });

            $('.lightbox2').click(function(){
                $('.backdrop, .box2').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.box2').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.backdrop, .box2').css('display', 'block');
            });


            $('.close').click(function(){
                close_box();
            });
        });

        function close_box()
        {
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
            });

            $('.backdrop, .box2').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                $('.backdrop, .box2').css('display', 'none');
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: By editing the file

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library - so there is nothing stopping you putting jQuery into a .js file

Comment: Or you can just save the jquery stuff in a different file and link it, I don't understand what difficulties you are having

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the existing jquery code and place it into the Websocket.js file.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best if you created a new `.js` file, copy and paste your script code into it and save it with a meaningful name. Finally, reference the new file just like you've done with the `WebSocket.js` file.